Поиск файла не используя его имени, адреса и другие изменяемые параметры
Какой параметр файла (например, txt файла) надо знать, кроме его имени, расширения его содержимого и адреса, чтобы можно было найти этот файл?
Может быть при создании файла ему присваивается пожизненный неизменяемый ID код, зная который этот файл можно будет найти?
Если такой ID код существует, то как его используя, найти данный файл?

Вообще говоря, всё очень зависит от файловой системы. Не знаю, может, вы имеете в виду inode в Linux или File ID в NTFS, но еще раз - все зависит от конкретной файловой системы.

Ответ: никакой, нет, никак. А чисто для удовлетворения любопытства: где собираетесь искать?

Если файл создан и больше никогда не будет изменён - можно попробовать искать по контрольной сумме, но уникальность тут не гарантирована, хотя при использовании какого-нибудь SHA-256 вероятность ошибки будет крайне мала

Что вы хотите от этого ID? Он должен меняться при редактировании файла? При копировании? При перемещении внутри файловой системы? При перемещении за пределы файловой системы? При архивировании и восстановлении из архива?

Только если поменяли имя или адрес или изменили текст, то я всё равно смогу найти этот файл и кажется я понял как. Роль уникального параметра данного конкретного файла может сыграть время его создания, например - Created:   ‎30 ‎September, ‎2023, ‏‎19:04:32. Такого же времени создания любого другого файла нет.
